# Dynamic button creation via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to query mysql via PHP to get a list of class names from a table. I then want the user to click on one of these class names to be redirected to a page which displays the class roster for whatever class was clicked on. The rosters are generated on-the-fly from another table in the database, right now I'd like to just save the class name as a session variable, then have the roster.php page use that variable to query for the correct roster.

ex.)

class a   -click-> roster.php

-> `echo (// roster 'a' as <ol> from table);`

class b  -click-> roster.php

-> `echo (// roster 'b' as <ol> from table);`

class a   -click-> roster.php

-> `echo (// roster 'c' as <ol> from table);`

I understand how to query and how to echo out html lists through a php page, **but I'm not sure how I would generate buttons for the class names, then have the webpage track which button is clicked on.**

Here is the code I have written to generate the rosters from the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM student_Data WHERE classs =" . $_SESSION['classname'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     echo("<div id=\"list1\">")
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo ("<li><h4 class=\"list-group-item-heading\">". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "</h4></li>");
     }
     echo("</div>");
} else {
     echo ("");
}
```

*Side note*: This is a personal project so I rather produce quick code over efficient code. Which is why I am OK with session vars.

Comment: What query do you want to run on roaster.php? The problem is simple enough, but its not clear what data is important for the query on the following page - the query in your code seems to be getting student data (first and last name) yet your question asks about class names

Comment: If you have a list of classes, can't you just loop over that list and output a link for each one?  It's almost identical to what you're doing now, except you'd output an `a` tag in your loop.

Comment: @Steve I would use the provided code to get the rosters on roster.php. That page would display student names. However, there are several different classes, so I would need to also pass on which class is being asked for to that roster.php page as well.

Comment: Well according to your code, that data is already in `$_SESSION['classname']`??

Comment: @Steve Ah, well you see I made that code with the assumption that page would have that data. However, the page before it with the buttons would actually be how that data gets set and stored. So classname is set on the button page according to which button is clicked. Then the roster page uses that to produce a query for students in the class which the user has clicked on. So if 'class a' button is clicked, roster.php queries for students in 'class a'.

Comment: @Christopher: You can accomplish that with a query string value instead of a session value.  A link can contain the identifier for the class, then when you get to the next page that identifier will be in the `$_GET` collection.

Comment: @David Hmm, could you form that into an answer format? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'then when you get to the next page that identifier will be in the $_GET collection'. I don't think I've ever done something like that in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output a list of class links in pretty much the exact same way you're outputting a list of students.  Assuming you have a database query in your previous page for the classes, it might look something like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo ("<a href=\"class.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">" . $row["name"] . "</a>");
}
```

So the resulting links would look something like this:

```
<a href="class.php?id=1">Class A</a>
<a href="class.php?id=2">Class B</a>
<a href="class.php?id=3">Class C</a>
```

Then in your next page, you can get the identifier from the query string with `$_GET["id"]`.  **Note** of course that this value *can be changed* by the user.  So you *do not* want to use it directly in a SQL query as you currently do with your session value.  (Which you shouldn't be doing either, really.)  Instead, use a prepared statement and bind this as a *value* instead of executing it as *code*.

Comment: Thank you David. I have dually noted your comment on the SQL injection. As stated, for this project it isn't a concern. It's just a little playground for me to learn the ropes :) This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string parameter:

Display buttons page:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, classname FROM classes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<ul id='list1'>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo sprintf("<li><a href='roaster.php?classId=%s'>%s</a></li>", $row['id'], $row['classname']);
     }
     echo "</ul>";
}
```

roaster page

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM student_Data WHERE classid =" . $_GET['classId'];
```

Note that you would want to handle missing / invalid ids, and properly protect against SQL injection, using prepared queries. This is not shown above for berevity